# Django ImportError no module named

Tags: python, django

I've been googling this all day and have not come across a solution, hope you can help:

Using Django 1.6, I made an app called "builds" as part of a project called "computerbuilder".

The site works fine when I use the test server, however I created a file to populate the database with some items, and it's giving me the error when I run `python fillDB.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "fillDB.py", line 1, in <module>
        from builds.models import BuildsTable
ImportError: No module named builds.models
```

This is my file fillDB.py:

```
from builds.models import BuildsTable

moboDB = open("db.txt", "r")
lines = moboDB.read().split('\",')
print lines

def main():
    global lines
    global BuildsTable

for item in lines:
    mobo = BuildsTable.objects.get(moboListing="%s" % item[0])
    price_local = BuildsTable.objects.get(moboListing="%s" % item[1])
    if(BuildsTable.objects.filter(
        moboListing = mobo, price = price_local).exists() == False):
            mydb = BuildsTable(moboListing = mobo, price = price_local)
            mydb.save()

main()
```

This is my models.py file from the "builds" app I made:

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.

class BuildsTable(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    moboListing = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

My directory looks like this:

```
├── builds
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── computerbuilder
│   ├── dev
│   │   ├── db.txt
│   │   ├── fillDB.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
└── requirements.txt
```

Since I'm using an external file not part of Django, I think that's why its having trouble recognizing it. Also using postgres if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the **init**.py in dev folder. Because it treated as a python package. Next you need to add your django project path in fillDB.py like this,

```
Root
 ├──├── builds
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── computerbuilder
    │   ├── dev
    │   │   ├── db.txt
    │   │   ├── fillDB.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── views.py
    │   ├── wsgi.py
    ├── manage.py
    └── requirements.txt
```

Follow the above folder structure,
And also you need to set the django environment variable to this file.

**fillDB.py**

```
import sys
import os


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.path.append('/path/Root')
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "computerbuilder.settings")

    from builds.models import BuildsTable

    mobo = BuildsTable.objects.all()
    print mobo
```

Hope this help you

Comment: thanks, so where it says `sys.path.append('/path/Root')` I have to change it to my path to my top level directory of the project?

Comment: Thanks, that worked! but now I have another problem with my code, will try to fix it, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Check you sys.path to see whether there have you path or not. Every time you run your python project, python will append you current path to the sys.path. And once you quit the python enviroment, python will remove the path you appended in.

Your problem is you run just run fillDB.py, python just append '../computerbuilder/dev' into sys.path, so python can not find builds module.

The solution is move your fillDB.py file to the same level as builds folder

```
├── builds    
├── fillDB.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── computerbuilder
│   ├── dev
│   │   ├── db.txt
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
└── requirements.txt
```

Hope it can help you :D

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried moving the files to the same directory as "builds", but  I got the same error, I also tried putting it in a separate folder at the same level, and got the same error.

But after I put the `fillDB.py` file at the same level as `manage.py`, I now get another error:
`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:`

`Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable 
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`